# Coreftp won't delete source

Tags: ftp

I'm using coreftp to automatically pull files daily from an external ftp via SFTP. I'm able to pull the files, however despite using the flag 'delsrc', it won't actually delete the source file meaning the files may build up. I think it may have to do with the fact that I can't push to the ftp, however I can delete the files through the coreftp GUI. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use use: "**FluentFTP**"

It is better than CoreFTP.